# React + Redux + Typescript Chrome Extension Popup Script - Redux Devtools Shows "No Store Found"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-devtools-extension

I am creating a chrome extension that is mainly served in a popup script.

### Manifest.json

```json
// public/manifest.json

{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "name": "__MSG_appName__",
  "description": "__MSG_appDesc__",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "author": "lbragile",
  "homepage_url": "some_url_not_relevant_to_question_at_hand",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "storage"],
  "optional_permissions": ["contextMenus", "alarms", "downloads", "downloads.shelf"],
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/logo16.png",
    "48": "images/logo48.png",
    "128": "images/logo128.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/logo16.png",
      "48": "images/logo48.png",
      "128": "images/logo128.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "title"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "incognito": "split"
}
```

### Package.json

```json
// package.json

{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "description",
  "author": "lbragile",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "nanoid": "^3.1.30",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.14",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.12",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.15",
    "@types/chrome": "0.0.159",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.10.3",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.19",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
    "@types/redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.13.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-styled-components-a11y": "0.0.34",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^22.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.59.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "npx eslint {src,public}/**/**/*.[jt]s -c config/.eslintrc.js --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:style": "npx stylelint {src,public}/**/**/*.css --config config/.stylelintrc.json",
    "start": "webpack --config config/webpack.config.js --watch --progress"
  },
  "babel": {
    "extends": "./config/.babelrc.json"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "./config/.eslintrc.js"
  },
  "stylelint": {
    "extends": "./config/.stylelintrc.json"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

### Webpack

```js
// config/webpack.config.js

const path = require("path");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    popup: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/index.tsx"),
    background: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/background.ts"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: "public", to: "." }],
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts(x)?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              mimetype: "image/png",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
  },
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, `../dist`),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
};
```

### Problem

I've tried `redux-devtools-extension`:

```
// src/index.tsx

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers";

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

which shows:

[image: No Store Found]

I've also tried using `remote-redux-devtools`:

```
// src/index.tsx

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import devToolsEnhancer from "remote-redux-devtools";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers";

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, devToolsEnhancer());

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

which seems more promising, but has no data in the store:

[image: Remote Redux Window]

When I run in the browser, using `npm start` (`react-scripts start`), I do see the store in the `Redux DevTools` extension, so I am not sure what the problem is.

### Possible Idea

When I build with React (`react-scripts build`), I can see the store just fine. The issue is that I cannot use react as it's build times are too slow and using webpack seems like the most logical alternative. Here is the build output:

[image: Working After React Build]

Any ideas?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, we do not edit the word "SOLVED" into the title and the solution into the question. If the answer did not answer your question, add your own answer and accept that answer. If the answer did answer your question (and by your comments it did), mark that answer as accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: this answer was originally added by OP as an edit to their original question, I have just reposted it as an answer.*

A **server** needs to be running and `remote redux devtools` should be used rather than `redux devtools extension`.

The best approach would be the following:

1. Install npmjs.com/package/remotedev-server
2. Add `"remotedev": "remotedev --hostname=localhost --port=8080"` npm script
3. Run the above script to start a server
4. Right click on popup, `Redux DevTools > Open Remote DevTools` **(not `inspect`)**
5. Settings > Use Custom Local Server > Type in the hostname and port specified in the npm script.

Here is what my store looks like:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "remote-redux-devtools";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers";

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({
  realtime: true,
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: 8080
});

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers());

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with webpack uglifying `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__`  in the following [code](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/npm-package/index.js#L6-L14)

You can try the following:

```
import { createStore, compose } from 'redux'
//same code as original but with bracket notation
const composeWithDevTools = (
  typeof window !== 'undefined' && window["__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__"] ?
    window["__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__"] :
    function() {
      if (arguments.length === 0) return undefined;
      if (typeof arguments[0] === 'object') return compose;
      return compose.apply(null, arguments);
    }
);
//your original code but using your composeWithDevTools 
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());
```

You don't need to import composeWithDevTools from redux-devtools-extension as you've created it yourself but if this solves the problem you should create an [issue](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues) requesting for bracket notation so uglify won't break the code.

To see what the compiled code is you can add a console log before your createStore: `console.log("creating store")` then you can disable source maps in chrome devtools (Command+Shift+P or Control+Shift+P) and then search for the console text `creating store` shortcut is: command+alt+f or control+shift+f)

Comment: That worked and it makes so much sense now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Although, it seems to not update the store when I dispatch an action, is it possible that I need to use the 'remote' version?

Comment: I created an issue: https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/820

Comment: It seems like it was a false positive (I had an existing tab from localhost:3000 that was created by react-scripts). So unfortunately, the above solution does not seem to work 

Comment: @lbragile What does the compiled code look like?

Comment: @lbragile You could create a minimal project that only has App component that dispatches "HELLO_WORLD" in an effect and share that on github. I suspect it has something to do with how it's compiled because react-scripts will work.

Comment: My code is open source, check out the master branch of https://github.com/lbragile/tabmerger

Comment: @lbragile One problem I can find is that you open index.html from file and not serving it. If you open a html file your redux devtool extension is not working. I had no problem with the code (as JS because could not easily get jsx to work) when I run it in a [server](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/TabMerger/tree/master/server) the redux devtools work.

Comment: Your suggesting gave me an idea and I finally cracked the code:

1. Install https://www.npmjs.com/package/remotedev-server
2. Add `"remotedev": "remotedev --hostname=localhost --port=8080"` npm script
3. Run the above script to start a server
4. Right click on popup, "Redux DevTools > Open Remote DevTools"
5. Settings > Use Custom Local Server > Type in the hostname and port specified in the npm script.

Thank you so much!